Rebase and fast-forward leads to more merge conflicts than Squash merge
I've used Squash merge in ADO but on this new project, the team is using Rebase & fast-forward. There are very frequent merge conflicts between PRs that didn't touch the same code. I haven't seen this with Squash merge.  What's going on here?
Is this to be expected? One PR merges and the next one almost always has a merge conflict.

Reference: ADO Merge Types documentation

I guess these are not conflicts per se but another commit was done/merged on the main branch in between, so you have to rebase. That's kinda the point of rebase.

they show up as merge conflicts in the ADO PR  @GaëlJ

Regarding: "One PR merges and the next one almost always has a merge conflict." Are your PRs dependent on each other? An example of this might be: suppose feature1 branches off of main, and feature2 branches off of feature1 before a PR for feature1 is completed. Is that a common workflow?

no, both branched off of main @TTT

OK. What branching strategy are you using? Is it just main and feature branches, or do you have other shared branches too? If you have other shared branches, what is their relationship with main (how are they merged into each other, if ever)?

Or, are the conflicts showing up after you try to complete the PR? If yes, do your PRs typically have new merge commits in them? (Maybe you merged main into your branch to resolve conflicts locally? Or maybe you merged another branch into yours as part of your PR?)

@spottedmahn, Do the merge conflicts occurs when you only use the "Rebase and fast-forward" method to all the previous an next PRs which merge to the same target branch, or you mix using "Squash merge" and "Rebase and fast-forward" between the PRs which merge to the same target branch?
